# Polymer 1.0 Data Binding with inline script tags

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is this possible to have data binding inside an inline script tag? For example:

```
<script src="{{url}}" class="{{klass}}"></script>

Polymer({
 is: "test-app",
 ready: function() {
    url = "http://google.com/js/some-file.js",
    klass = "script-class"
 }
});
```

Based on the [Polymer 1.0 Data Binding docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html), I could not come up with anything better.

I have edited this post to 100% clarity of what I want to achieve. I want to use [Strip Embedded Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/checkout):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_blahblah"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

**Mason's answer and Anthony's clue led me to this:**

```
<dom-module id="my-app>
 <template>
   <form action="" method="POST">
        <script
          src$="{{url}}" class$="{{klass}}"
          data-key$="{{key}}"
          data-amount$="{{total}}"
          data-name$="{{dname}}"
          data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
          data-image="/128x128.png">
        </script>
      </form>
 </template>
 <script>
   Polymer({
        is: "my-app",
        properties: {
           selection: {
            type: String,
            observation: "selectionChanged"
           }
        },
    ready: function() {
          this.url = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js';
          this.klass = 'stripe-button';
          this.key = 'pk_test_blahblah';
          this.dname = 'Demo';
          // this.total = "333"; // this value is not static
        },
    selectionChanged: function () {
      if (true) {
       this.total = 50; // I need this to assign to "{{total}}" in the template.
      }
    };
 </script>
</dom-module>
```

How can I get the value of `this.total` to be assigned to `data-amount` in the script tag of Stripe's?

**[See Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MolopK?)**

Comment: Have you tried the `$=` syntax mentioned here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding It works for `class`, not sure about the script tag though. Also, you should be using `this.url=` and `this.klass=`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/41QgMW?p=info) and it seems it's not possible to do this.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <script src="{{url}}"></script>
    Try to load <span>{{name}}</span>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    ready: function() {
      this.name = 'JQuery';
      this.url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';

      this.async(function() {
        this.name = 'AngularJs';
        this.url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js';
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The first loading works but when the bind value has changed, Polymer does not create a new *script* tag for you. You can create a script tag by using the DOM.

*Edited:*

Initializing the script tag's attributes without "ready" method.

```
<template>
  <script src="{{_url}}"></script>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  properties: {
    _url: {
      type: String,
      value: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Or using hosted attributes

```
<template>
  <script src="{{url}}"></script>
  Try to load <span>{{name}}</span>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  hostAttributes: {
    url: {
      type: String
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

and in the parent element:

```
<my-element url="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></my-element>
```

By using *hostAttributes* you'll see the url in the DOM.

Comment: I have partially got this to work with anythony's advice: `$=`. I have a function that assigns `this.url`, how to pass that to the script tag without using the ready function?

Comment: I see 2 ways to do this. Use private properties or public attributes. I updated my post above.

Comment: @Manson The post has yet to be updated. Have you done so?

Comment: Ok that worked as described but the thing is, Im not using `<my-app></my-app>` import, I want to use the function in the same html, is that possible?

Comment: @Sylar In fact yes. I should not have said "in the parent". You can put the _my-element_ tag anywhere (even in the file where it is described), just import the element if needed.

Comment: No sure I follow. See my edited question where I have the function `selectionChanged`. I need `this.total`'s value to pass to `data-amount`. I cant use `<my-element amount="({{total}}"></my-element>`

Comment: Could you make a _Plunkr_ ? I'll work on it when I'll have more time. For now, I have to go back to work :). (Check you have declared the _amount_ as public property. `properties: {amount: {type: Number}}`)

Comment: I'll do that when I reach work. I have not declared `amount`. I'll try that first later. Thanks for the continued support.

Comment: I have added a Plunkr. See above post.

Comment: I updated your [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HVpSJY?p=info) but I don't know if you want just initialize the amount or not, so I have written some comments.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look soon as I've reached home as I'm on mobile.

Comment: Same thing, nothing changes. I'll have a sit down and figure this one out. The aim is to grab the value of `this.total` and to push it to `{{total}}`. `this.total` has different values based on the user section (true or false).